# Which preposition is correct with "settling"? The complete sentence is given below

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, descriptive-grammar

This is the complete question which I came across during a competitive exam.

*Eager to control the South Atlantic, the British Navy had tasked Admiral Byron ________ **(with/for)** settling an island off the South American coast where ships could resupply, and then finding an alternative route to the East Indies.*

I am confused about which preposition should be used before "settling" and why?

Comment: The correct question is: What is the correct preposition for the verb **task**,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'with settling' is the correct expression here.

Generally we task someone **with** some job to do.

We might ask someone **for** some job to be done.

Some examples.

> He was tasked with cleaning his room.
>
> She asked for furniture to be delivered.

Comment: Now I can understand that here preposition is used according to 'task', not 'settling'.